# Nielsen and Chuang, Exercise 6.5: How to simulate oracle for n+1 qubits using one oracle gate for n qubits and one extra qubit?

Tags: grovers-algorithm, nielsen-and-chuang, oracles

In Chapter 6 of "Quantum Computation and Quantum Information" textbook by Nielsen and Chuang, Exercise 6.5 p.255:

> We have an oracle gate $O$ for $n$ qubit ($2^n=N$ searching items),
>    and we would like to construct new oracle gate $O'$ for $n+1$ qubit ($2^{n+1}=2N$ searching items) using oracle gate $O$ and extra bit $|q\rangle$ so that new oracle gate $O'$ should mark an item only if it is solution for the oracle gate $O$ and extra bit $|q\rangle$ is $|0\rangle$.

The exact question in the Nielsen and Chuang textbook as follows:

> A *new augmented* oracle $O'$ is constructed which marks an item only
>   if it is a solution to the search problem and the extra bit is set to zero.
>
> Exercise 6.5: Show that the augmented oracle $O'$ may be constructed using one
>   application of $O$, and elementary quantum gates, using the extra qubit $|q\rangle$.

### Possible not very good solutions:

[image]

The problem with this solution is related to the fact that it requires to open up an Oracle gate $O$ in order to "control" it.

Does anybody have an idea of how to construct gate $O'$ using "pure" gate $O$ without "open up" them?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The simplest solution is to use an ancilla in the $|+\rangle$ state. Swap that ancilla for the oracle's output qubit, conditioned on the control qubit being false, before and after applying the oracle. Since toggling the $|+\rangle$ state has no effect, this deactivates the oracle when the control is set.

Here's this technique applied to [a simple comparison oracle](https://algassert.com/quirk#circuit=%7B%22cols%22%3A%5B%5B1%2C%22QFT7%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C%22inputA7%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22%2B%3DA7%22%5D%2C%5B%22Swap%22%2C%22%E2%97%A6%22%2C%22Swap%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C%22%5EA%3CB%22%2C%22inputA3%22%2C1%2C1%2C%22inputB2%22%5D%2C%5B%22Swap%22%2C%22%E2%97%A6%22%2C%22Swap%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C%22%E2%80%A6%22%2C%22%E2%80%A6%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C%22%5EA%3CB%22%2C%22inputA3%22%2C1%2C1%2C%22inputB2%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C%22inputA7%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22-%3DA7%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C%22QFT%E2%80%A07%22%5D%5D%2C%22init%22%3A%5B%22%2B%22%5D%7D):

[image: ancilla solution]

If you're not allowed to use an ancilla, I'm not sure how to make it work unless you have access to the square root of the oracle. The best I know how to do is to have the controlled oracle bitflip *and phaseflip* the target. Or to bitflip the target but have a 90 degree phase kickback onto the control for satisfying inputs.

[image: bit flip and phase flip]

[image: bit flip and kickback]

**Summary Update - simple solution with ancilla**
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, your ideas push me to the following solution (i put it in the answer). It looks quite simple.

Comment: So, we actually can control an unknown black box if it just permutes a known basis. Nice.

Comment: i add summary scheme with ancilla to your answer

Answer (score 3):

Ancilla-free solution: replace the two controlled-SWAPs in the "summary update" of Craig Gidney's solution with controlled-$Z$s between the second and fourth qubits in the diagram, and remove the third qubit.

(That is, instead of swapping $|-\rangle$ with a $|+\rangle$ state stored in the second register, conditioned on $|q\rangle$ being set to 1, conditionally change $|-\rangle$ to $|+\rangle$ directly using controlled-$Z$.)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible. I think that was the authors idea - to apply controlled $O$
(despite the fact it's impossible to control black boxed unitaries https://arxiv.org/abs/1309.7976)

**Update**

As Craig Gidney answer suggests, we actually can control unknown black boxes if they just permute a known basis. Though we need to use an ancilla.

Answer (score 0):

After some ideas of @Craig Gidney probably i found the following simple solution:
[image]

Comment: This solution is not correct. It leaves the |x> register entangled with the ancilla qubit. You need to uncompute the ancilla qubit.

Comment: by "ancilla qubit" - you mean second cubit $|0\rangle$? What do you mean by "uncompute"? If $|x\rangle$ - the searching item (solution) and $|q\rangle$=$|0\rangle$, then $O'$$|x\rangle|0_q\rangle = -|x\rangle|0_q\rangle$. If  If $|x\rangle$ - the searching item (solution) and $|q\rangle$=$|1\rangle$, then $O'$$|x\rangle|1_q\rangle = |x\rangle|1_q\rangle$.  If $|x\rangle$ is not the searching item and $|q\rangle$=$|0\rangle$ or $|1\rangle$  , then $O'$$|x\rangle|0_q\rangle = |x\rangle|0_q\rangle$ or $O'$$|x\rangle|1_q\rangle = |x\rangle|1_q\rangle$.

Comment: Why you think that entangling between $|x\rangle$ and ancillary is a bed practice? In order to uncompute ancilla qubit i need to use oracle $O$ second time that is not good.

Comment: It's bad practice because it doesn't maintain coherence. If you try to use this implementation of the oracle within Grover's algorithm, the algorithm will fail. You're leaking information into the ancilla.